# How can I introduce a partition between the categories of a stacked bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Current:

[image]

Needed: A white space between red and blue categories

[image]

Data:

[image]

Comment: Just add `colour = "white"` to your `geom_col` or `geom_bar` call.

Comment: And you can control the width of the white line with `size=1`, `size=0.5`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the great comments of @AllanCameron and @eipi10 here is the code for what you want:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(class=c('1st class','1st class','2nd class','2nd class','3rd class','3rd class'),
                 sex=rep(c('male','female'),3),
                 n=c(179,143,172,107,499,212))
#Code
ggplot(df,aes(x=class,y=n,fill=sex,label=n))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='white',size=1)+
geom_text(color='white',position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),fontface='bold')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#cb5e5f", "#0072b1")) +
  theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "b")
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `scale_fill_manual(c("#cb5e5f", "#0072b1")) + theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "b")` for a closer reproduction

Comment: Now updated with the thankfully help of @AllanCameron !

Comment: @AllanCameron I haven't noticed about the labels, I just added so your help about closer reproduction is complete!